# Keycloak behind reverse proxy mixes internal and external addresses

Tags: docker-compose, keycloak, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to setup a keycloak instance behind a reverse proxy with nginx and I almost did it.

My (partial) docker-compose:

```
version: '3.4'                                                                          
                                                                                    
services:  
  [...]
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  keycloak:                                                                             
    image: jboss/keycloak                                                                                                                                     
    environment:                                                                        
      - DB_VENDOR=[vendor]
      - DB_USER=[user]                                                                      
      - DB_PASSWORD=[password]
      - DB_ADDR=[dbaddr]
      - DB_DATABASE=[dbname]
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=[adminuser]                                                         
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=[adminpassword]                                                       
      - KEYCLOAK_IMPORT=/tmp/my-realm.json                                           
      - KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL=https://auth.mydomain.blah/auth                          
      - PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true                                                   
      - REDIRECT_SOCKET=proxy-https
                                                 
  [...]
```

my nginx conf is just

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  auth.mydomain.blah;
  
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/auth.mydomain.blah/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/auth.mydomain.blah/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://keycloak:8080;
    }
}
```

and it works, I can access keycloak from `https://auth.mydomain.blah/auth` **BUT** when I look at `https://auth.mydomain.blah/auth/realms/campi/.well-known/openid-configuration` I get this:

```
{
  "issuer": "https://auth.mydomain.blah/auth/realms/campi",
  "authorization_endpoint": "https://auth.mydomain.blah/auth/realms/campi/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
  "token_endpoint": "http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/campi/protocol/openid-connect/token",
  "introspection_endpoint": "http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/campi/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect",
  "userinfo_endpoint": "http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/campi/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
  "end_session_endpoint": "https://auth.mydomain.blah/auth/realms/campi/protocol/openid-connect/logout",
  "jwks_uri": "http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/campi/protocol/openid-connect/certs",
  "check_session_iframe": "https://auth.mydomain.blah/auth/realms/campi/protocol/openid-connect/login-status-iframe.html",
  [...]
```

why does keycloak mix internal and external uris? what am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#_setting-up-a-load-balancer-or-proxy

Your reverse proxy/nginx is not forwarding host headers properly, so Keycloak has no idea which host/protocol has been used for the request and it using backend/internal host name. You need to set a few `proxy_set_header` lines:

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  auth.mydomain.blah;
  
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/auth.mydomain.blah/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/auth.mydomain.blah/privkey.pem;

    location / {
            proxy_pass          http://keycloak:8080;
            proxy_set_header    Host               $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    }
}
```

Comment: for HAProxy you just need to add  http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https

Answer (score -1):

We have the same "issue" at my company.

Internally access it via keycloak-admin.internaldomain.com but externally for our normal users they hit keycloak.externaldomain.com.

If I load the .well-known/openid-configuration url internally it has the internal address, but loading it using the external url it has that one.

It hasn't caused any issues at all for us, other than explaining it occasionally to an engineer that sees the difference. Otherwise though, no issues.

It appears keycloak just uses whatever domain it is being accessed with.

Comment: yeah but we don't need to call it internally, and having those mixed urls messes up our client applications

Comment: if the client applications access it via the desired public url it should be fine no?

Comment: yes, but it needs the correct token endpoint to work, not the internal address